# my program shows "filename.exe" has stopped working while i use the program for large data

Tags: c

HI I'm trying to built a program in c which can process data of around 600,000 first i tried to take data from a file and store them in array with a simple program but it showed like" filname.exe" has stopped. When i checked the same program with around 25 data it worked successfully could you please suggest what could be the problem. my code is like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    int i,j;
    unsigned int x[1024][512];

    ptr_file =fopen("output.txt", "r");

    if (!ptr_file)
        printf("the file can't be opened");

    for (i=0;i<1024; i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<512;j++)
        {
            fscanf(ptr_file,"%d\n", &x[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("%d",x[1024][511]);
    printf("%d",x[0][2]);
    fclose(ptr_file);

    return  0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned int x[1024][512];
// ...
printf("%d",x[1024][511]);
```

Array index needs to be `1023, 511`.

Comment: Now i got new problem ...when i run my program i need to display output in more than thousand line. but the display is only showing around last 400/500 lines of my output. How can i display all my output.I'm using codeblocks 10 with GNU-GCC

Answer (score 1):

> How can i display all my output.

Write your output into a file.